# Enter key press opens the dialog box in prime faces data table

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable in which I have implemented the cell editor feature. I have two columns with edit and delete functionality. When I click on the edit the cell editor shows and the user can edit the values and save them. In the same way when the user clicks on delete a dialog pops up with user details.Now my issue is when I click edit and when i focus on one of my input fields and press enter the dialog pops up.I do not want this to happen:Here is my JSF code:

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{mybean.userList}"
                                 var="item"
                                 id="dataTab"
                                 widgetVar="usersTable"
                                 tableStyleClass="data"  paginator="true" rows="5"  
                                 filteredValue="#{userController.filteredUsers}"
                                 editable="true"
                                 rowKey="#{item}"
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit"   listener="#{mybean.onEdit}" update=":userForm:growl" />  
                        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{mybean.onCancel}" update=":userForm:growl" /> 
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel>  
                             <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                             <p:inputText id="globalFilter"     onkeyup="('usersTable').filter()"   style="width:150px" />  
                        </p:outputPanel>     
                        </f:facet>


                        <p:column sortBy="#{item.firstName}" filterBy="#{item.firstName}" 
                                  filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                             <p:cellEditor> 
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                            <h:outputText value="First Name" />  
                            </f:facet>
                                 <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{item.firstName}" />
                                 </f:facet>
                                 <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{item.firstName}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
                              </p:cellEditor>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column  sortBy="#{item.lastName}" filterBy="#{item.lastName}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <p:cellEditor> 
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                            <h:outputText value="Last Name" />  
                            </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Update" style="width:6%">  
                         <p:rowEditor />  
                        </p:column>    


<p:column>
        <p:commandButton  oncomplete="delUserConf.show();" update=":userForm:display" >
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{myController.selectedUser}" />

     </p:commandButton> 
        </p:column>

                                            </p:dataTable>


    <p:dialog id="modalDialog"
                                              header="Delete User?"
                                              modal="true"
                                              resizable="false"
                                              draggable="false"
                                              widgetVar="delUserConf"
                                              >  

                       <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" style="width: 150px;">
                                            <h:outputLabel value="Firat Name"  style="font-weight: bold"/>

                                            <h:outputText value="Last Name"  style="border: none"/>

                                        </h:panelGrid>

                                    </p:dialog>
```

Can anyone let me know how I can avoid this?Thanks.

Comment: I'm just comment 'on the fly' but do you have `onclick` attribute on `rowEditor` component? If so, try to catch the pressed but with javascript...or maybe you can replace your commandButton by commandLink (this is just an idea)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the command button responds to the Enter key, even when it doesn't have focus?

Comment: @danRod I do not have a onClick on the rowEditor...I tried replacing it with commandlink and the same happenss......

Comment: @kolossus Yeah when i focus on the input field in the table to edit the data and press enter the dialog pops up...the dialog box generally pops up when i click the delete button....Could you let me know how I can resolve this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this will help you. My advice is you have to add this to your wrapper form of `<p:dataTable value="#{mybean.userList}"...`

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false; }"
```

Suppose if your wrapper form of  `<p:dataTable>` is `<h:form id="formm">`
 Then you have to edit your form tag like

```
<h:form id="formm" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return false; }">
```

Comment: Hello, With this solution the enter button functionality is disabled. But how can you still have the enter button working but without this behaviour?
And what is the cause for that?